# HTML5 Audio - Getting frequency array full of zeros

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, audiocontext

I'm having a bit of a trouble building an Audio frequency visualization. I am using HTML5 audio tag:

```
<audio id="music" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/02dcea11-9bd2-4462-ac38-eeb6a5ad9530%2F331_full_beautiful-minds_0171_preview.mp3?1522829295082" crossorigin="use-URL-credentials" controls="true"></audio>
```

*(song is from www.premiumbeat.com)*

used with AudioContext and Analyser as shown below:

```
const audio = document.getElementById('music');
audio.load();
audio.play();

const ctx = new AudioContext();
const audioSrc = ctx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
const analyser = ctx.createAnalyser();
audioSrc.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(ctx.destination);

analyser.fftSize = 256;
const bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
const frequencyData = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);

setTimeout(() => {
   analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);
   console.log(frequencyData);
}, 5000);
```

**Output:**
Even though the song is playing when I call the getByteFrequencyData(), the output is 128 items long array full of zeros.

**Expected behaviour:**
After 5 seconds console should output 128 items long array of current frequency data. (I do it this way because requestAnimationFrame would lag the window, however I tried it and the result is the same).

Any idea what I do wrong? *(I'm using Firefox Quantum 59.0.2.)*

Try it here: [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/kq8ckn7k/)

Thank you!

Comment: It's not full of zeros here `"0": 191,
  "1": 209,
  "2": 219,
  "3": 208,
  "4": 207,
  "5": 195,
  "6": 167,
  "7": 145,
  "8": 151,`

Comment: Oh, interesting! Mine is full of zeros - I'm using Firefox Quantum 59.0.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following my experiments with the web audio api i modified your script to use `getByteTimeDomainData` instead of `getByteFrequencyData`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getByteTimeDomainData

Using intervals instead of timeout for the demo.

```js
const audio = document.getElementById('music');
audio.load();
audio.play();

const ctx = new AudioContext();
const audioSrc = ctx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
const analyser = ctx.createAnalyser();

audioSrc.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(ctx.destination);

analyser.fftSize = 256;
const bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
const frequencyData = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

setInterval(() => {
   analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);
   console.log(frequencyData);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<audio id="music" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/02dcea11-9bd2-4462-ac38-eeb6a5ad9530%2F331_full_beautiful-minds_0171_preview.mp3?1522829295082" crossorigin="use-URL-credentials" controls="true"></audio>
```

Comment: Wow, amazing, this actually worked! Thanks! Is there a reason Why do I need to mix getByteTimeDomainData in the beggining with the getByteFrequencyData in the interval?

Comment: Well this is weird. After running your code here even my UNCHANGED project start working.

Comment: On a usability note for future visitors finding this question, web audio can only play after page interaction, simply loading audio with autoplay or JS-based "blah.play()" will not do anything until the user has interacted with the page (unfortunately) e.g. by clicking a button or the like.